# How can I make this sentence reverse algorithm more efficient?

Tags: python-3.x

The goal is to reverse a sentence's words while maintaining the punctuation. It looks a bit inefficient to me. Is there a better way to do this?

```
def revSentence(x):
    x= x.split()
    punc = ".!?;"
    front = 0
    end = len(x)-1
    while front < end:
        fp=""
        ep=""
        if x[front][-1] in punc:
               fp =x[front][-1]
               x[front]= x[front][:-1]
        elif x[end][-1] in punc: 
            ep =x[end][-1]
            x[end]= x[end][:-1]
        temp = x[front] + ep
        x[front] = x[end]+ fp
        x[end] = temp
        front+= 1
        end-= 1
    return ' '.join(x)

print(revSentence("I like eggs. And Ice cream!"))
```

expected output:

`cream Ice And. eggs like I!`

Comment: Is the second one technically even a sentence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that was even a thing. I'll do that next time thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex patterns to separate the punctuation from words could be a shorter way:

```
import re
def revSentence(s):
    words = reversed(re.split(r'[\W]+', s))
    punc = re.split(r'[\w]+', s)
    rev = "".join(w + punc[i] for i, w in enumerate(words))
    return rev

print(revSentence("I like eggs. And Ice cream!"))
```

will also print

`cream Ice And. eggs like I!`